# Какую БД использовать для приложения под андроид, чтобы был доступ с разных устройств в любое время. с

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Какую базу данных можно использовать для приложение 
Нужна возможность регистрации/входа, наличие виртуальной валюты, что бы человек мог сам поменять логин/пароль
При этом что бы был доступ с любого устройства и администратор мог добавить валюты, а пользователь что-то за неё купить.
Я нашёл пока что firebase и SQLite, но с последним не понимаю, как вывести в сеть.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужны 2 базы данных.

Одна должна быть на клиентском девайсе, вторая - на сервере. Вторая должна быть, по хорошему, защищена обёрткой API над собственно БД.

На клиентском девайсе самый распространённый вариант - SQLite (либа Room). Её не нужно делать доступной из сети - в ней просто будет копия серверной БД. При этом, по идее, от БД на девайсе можно вообще отказаться, если достаточно, чтобы приложение работало только при работающем интрнете и отображало только то, что пришло с сервера.

На сервере можно использовать любую БД. Firebase хорош только тем, что не требует знания того, как сделать сервер, запустить на нём СУБД и обернуть запросы к ней в API. Плох он тем, что не имея очень большого опыта и точного знания ожидаемого трафика вы быстро вылезете за бесплатный лимит. И траты в итоге могут быть очень существенными. Также это NoSQL. Он не идеален в большинстве стандартный случаев хранения связанных данных и требует очень большого опыта для правильного построения схемы данных. И самое важное - это собственность Google, а Google - корпорация зла. Лучше лишний раз не марать руки. С другой стороны, поднятие сервера - сложный процесс. Но в большинстве случаев это в итоге будет правильный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите, какие серверные БД можно использовать, и где почитать про них

Comment: @KaRtoHHka, возьмите `Postgresql`. Почитать про неё можно у них на сайте.